# Testing nodejs application performance

Tags: node.js, heroku, performance-testing

Are there best practices for testing nodejs application performance?

I'm guessing they could fall under many different types of testing (load, speed, stress). I'd like to do all of the above to find weak areas of my API and/or bits of code that are slow, maybe find some areas that can be done in parallel. Are there packages for this? I've found [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest) which looks promising.

Also, I'm using Heroku for deployment, so if there's any heroku-specific stuff out there, that would also be appreciated. I know they scale automatically with the dynos so that shouldn't be an issue. Anyway, any pointers would be appreciated, I've never had to test much in a node app before besides unit tests.

Comment: Hopefully you've found out some good ways for testing performance since then. Maybe you could share your findings as an answer ?